# How do I set up my config files in Rails to get SendGrid to work in Heroku? AuthenticationError (535 failed: Bad username / password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, sendgrid, figaro-ruby

I'm trying to set up active mailer functionality in my Rails app with Devise and SendGrid so that users can receive a confirmation email when they sign up and can request a forgot password link. When I deploy to Heroku and try and sign up I get an error when I hit 'sign up'. In the Heroku logs the I can see that there is an error as follows:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 547ms (ActiveRecord: 8.1ms)
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535 Authentication failed: Bad username / password
```

It's probably something to do with the way I have my config files but I can't put my finger on it. Any help would be massively appreciated! Here are my files.

**config/application.yml**

```
production:
  SECRET_KEY_BASE: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>

development:
 GMAIL_USERNAME: scott.ian.munro@gmail.com
 GMAIL_PASSWORD: password
 SENDGRID_USERNAME: app115625999@heroku.com
 SENDGRID_PASSWORD: password

test:
 GMAIL_USERNAME: scott.ian.munro@gmail.com
 GMAIL_PASSWORD: password
 SENDGRID_USERNAME: app115625999@heroku.com
 SENDGRID_PASSWORD: password

production:
 GMAIL_USERNAME: scott.ian.munro@gmail.com
 GMAIL_PASSWORD: password
 SENDGRID_USERNAME: app115625999@heroku.com
 SENDGRID_PASSWORD: password
```

I'm using the `figaro` gem to manage my environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem appears to be that you're referencing `GMAIL_USERNAME` and `GMAIL_PASSWORD` instead of `SENDGRID_USERNAME` and `SENDGRID_PASSWORD`, and you're still referencing the Gmail SMTP server and port.

Assuming you're using this gem: https://github.com/stephenb/sendgrid, this should do the trick for your production config file:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
   address: "smtp.sendgrid.com",
   port: 25,
   domain: "heroku.com",
   authentication: :plain,
   user_name: ENV["SENDGRID_USERNAME"],
   password: ENV["SENDGRID_PASSWORD"],
}
```

Update: per you comment that you're using the `figaro` gem, make sure to run the rake task that adds the `ENV` variables to Heroku:
`rake figaro:heroku`

Comment: Sorry, I had actually posted the wrong code for my production file (have updated now). I actually already have `SENDGRID_USERNAME` and `SENDGRID_PASSWORD` in there and still get the error.

Comment: @ NM Pennypacker Also, when I try these in the console I get `nil`

p ENV[‘SECRET_DEV_KEY’]
p ENV[‘SECRET_KEY_TEST’]
p ENV[‘SECRET_KEY_BASE’]

Comment: You may have to add the `ENV` variables somewhere in the Heroku admin UI. If they're coming up `nil` in the console, they're not being loaded. How are you loading the data from application.yaml into the app?

Comment: I'm using the figaro gem, basically following [this](https://medium.com/@cheney.shreve/using-devise-with-gmail-sendgrid-rails-and-heroku-tips-to-save-time-debugging-626546118358) tutorial

Comment: See the Update: Looks like your ENV variables aren't making it to Heroku

Comment: it doesn't recognise that command: rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'figaro:heroku' (see --tasks)
/home/scott_imunro/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/home/scott_imunro/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'

Comment: I don't think it's a heroku issue as i'm getting errors in development too: `Puma caught this error: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'development' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml` (RuntimeError)`

Comment: Then you probably have to install the heroku command line tools. Either way, you'll have to be able to run that command

Answer (score 0):

I use more params too:

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    .
    .
    .
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    openssl_verify_mode:  "none"
  }

:)